Start docker service (Swarm) using wiremock image but with arguments
I am creating a docker service using the following command
docker service create --name my-service --network my-network -p 9999:8080 wiremock/wiremock
While this is getting created but I want the service to also support JSON files under wiremock directory i.e. /mappings/my-json.json
I tried to start the service using arguments like
docker service create --name my-service --network my-network -p 9999:8080 wiremock/wiremock --command "/docker-entrypoint.sh --global-response-templating --persist-mappings" 
but this is indefinitely not starting the service
I also tried to copy the file, which I am able to but as soon as the service scales down (For a restart) the file definitely is removed when service is scaled up.
Moreover, previously I tried without --command as well
Basically my motive is that service created using wiremock supports JSON files as well as mocking stubs using API

Tried with this docker service create --name my-service --network my-network -p 9999:8080 wiremock/wiremock --command "/docker-entrypoint.sh --global-response-templating" without persist-mappings somehow it worked, but the motive is not being achived
